# Logout from android sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, exit, logout

Is there any any easy way to log out from sq-lite database? Can I use simple function on back key that will behave as "Home key" pressed and take the user out of my application?  is it practically feasible?

If so then guide me .. Thanks in advance :)

I have seen this code here on stack over flow .. how can it help me ?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: You don't log out of SQLite databases. You just `SQLiteDatabaseOpenHelper.close()` them when you're done. Maybe you need to explain why you are actually trying to do this; perhaps you are confused somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can close connection with sqlite database using  sqliteDatabaseobject.close() method 
in onStop() or onPause() method & u can again connected sqlite database using method onStart() or onResume() method